# F# Web API - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: web-services, exception, f#, owin

I am trying to create an F# web service using OWIN, I have found 2 tutorials online and both are give me the same error of "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" on the same line of code but I can not figure out why this is happening

```
use server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAddress)
```

Below is a a short piece of code I am using the second and more complex example can be found [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work/) on the forfunandprofit website example number 3

```
namespace FSharpWebAPIOwin

open Owin
open System.Web.Http
open System.Collections.Generic
open Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
open System

module main = 

type Startup() =
    member this.Configuration(app : IAppBuilder) = 
        let config = new HttpConfiguration()
        let route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                                                "Default", 
                                                "api/{controller}/{id}" )
        route.Defaults.Add("id", RouteParameter.Optional )

        app.UseWebApi(config) |> ignore

type HelloController() =
    inherit ApiController()

    member this.Get() = 
        "hello"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000"
    use server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAddress)
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit ... ")
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Exception Details

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder)
   at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider services, StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](String url)
   at FSharpWebAPIOwin.main.main(String[] argv) in C:\Users\amulligan\Desktop\Api\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.fs:line 30
  InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException
   HResult=-2146234304
   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0,       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   Source=ConsoleApplication2
   FileName=System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
   FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = CCS\amulligan
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase =      file:///C:/Users/amulligan/Desktop/Api/ConsoleApplication2/ConsoleApplication2/bin/Debug/
     LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : ConsoleApplication2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\amulligan\Desktop\Api\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/amulligan/Desktop/Api/ConsoleApplication2/ConsoleApplication2/bin/Debug/System.Web.Http.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

   StackTrace:
        at FSharpWebAPIOwin.main.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: Usually, that error message comes from a `TargetInvocationException`; it'll normally have an `InnerException` that contains the original exception. Does your exception have an `InnerException`, and if so: what does it say?

Comment: System.IO.FileLoadException: A FileLoadException exception is thrown when a managed assembly is found but cannot be loaded.

Comment: Is "A FileLoadException exception is thrown when a managed assembly is found but cannot be loaded." really the value of the `Message` property of the `FileLoadException`?

Comment: Added exception details to original question. Is that what your looking for Mark

Comment: It says: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0...". Do you have that assembly in your probing path, or GAC?

Comment: I looked in C:\Windows\assembly and there is no System.Web.http but there is system.web

Comment: You should look in your nuget package. System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0 comes as nuget package installation. Then look into your Api/bin folder for a correct version